# Как правильно создать http ответ из PHP скрипта?

Tags: php, post

Делаю POST-запрос из своего JS в свой PHP скрипт, как правильно создавать тело ответа которое отправляется из PHP в JS. Случайно заметил что print_r , и видимо любой вывод данных, записывается в тело ответа. Но правильно ли так отправлять ответ?

Comment: Стандарт обмена - json. Можно также - xml. Ну и просто plain text тоже никто не отменял.

Comment: по вашему ответ для js чем-то отличается от ответа на обычный запрос?

Comment: То есть это правильно так отправлять ответ, через print_r("тело_ответа")?

Comment: а при чем здесь print_r()? Эта функция вообще никогда не должна использоваться. А в остальном тебе уже сказали, **ответ для js ничем не отличается от ответа на любой другой запрос**

Comment: Какие функции нужно использовать для создания http-ответа в PHP?

Comment: @ИгорьМихайлов такие же, как для создания обычного http ответа. `echo` и пр. JS увидит то же, что и вы, если страницу просто в браузере наберете, разницы никакой.

Comment: Спасибо, теперь понятно

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ответ от php должен приходить в формате json. Для этого можно загнать все нужные значения в массив и использовать функцию json_encode.

А, при отправке ajax, в dataType указать json.

Пример ответа сервера:

`<?php echo json_encode(['message': 'Ответ получен!']); ?>`

Comment: Почему должен? Кому должен?

Comment: @u_mulder, имеется ввиду, что так будет лучше для него. Да и в основном, когда делают запросы на получение данных (а не страницих и т.п.), то ответ получают json'ом.

Comment: А во вторых - второй аргумент функции json_encode - это int.

Comment: @u_mulder, точно, что-то я загнался. Это в json_decode.

Comment: Спасибо, теперь понятно